# getStaticProps does not fire on iis until I refresh whole page

Tags: javascript, iis, next.js, url-rewriting

I used nextjs getStaticProps feature in project and everything works fine.

After uploading Static files to iis, it feature won't work until I configure a urlRewrite module on it.
So when I first initially visit one page, getStaticProps is not fired until I refresh a whole page.
Here are codes Im used for urlRewrite module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="ReactRouter Routess" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="product\/(\d+)\/.*" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/product/{R:1}.html" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Why and How Can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

**getStaticProps** is run **during the build process**, when given page is pre-rendered, not during the request (see more details [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props)) - that's why you're not seeing it executed on your first request. If you want this page to be always `"fresh"`, replace **getStaticProps** with **getServerSideProps** (more info [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)).

**getStaticProps** can only be run post-build when a page gets revalidated - either due to the fact that the `revalidate` period is over or revalidation was triggered programatically. That's probably what triggered this function execution in your case. You can learn more about this process [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration).

Comment: As is mentioned by jedrzej, there could be some delay in the refresh of the page when using getStaticProps. This delay is due to the set of revalidate. E.g. if the revalidate time is set to ‘30’, then all visitors will see the same generated version of the site for the next 30 seconds. And only after this time the refreshed page can be seen by someone visiting this site.

Comment: Plus, the first person that visits the page after 30 seconds will see the old version, but still trigger revalidation. People that visit the page afterwards, will see the updated page.